# What do the digits in WELL generators represent?

Tags: random

In psuedo-random number generators like WELL512a, WELL1024, and WELL44497b, I understand what WELL (well equidistributed long-period linear) stands for, but I can't find any information on the suffix. 
I'm writing a paper over rng's and I'm not sure if this is relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question, and I'm sure that OP has moved on, but others may be interested in the answer.  @SeverinPappadeux's answer is pretty much correct.  The number *n* in the suffix is the roughly number of bits in the internal state.  The period is 2<sup>*n*</sup> - 1.  The letters after the numbers indicate different variants of the PRNG with the corresponding period.  The different letters don't have any meaning other than indicating different versions.

The Wikipedia page is very brief:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_equidistributed_long-period_linear

This is the official paper on the WELL generators:
[http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/wellrng.pdf](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Elecuyer/myftp/papers/wellrng.pdf)

The table on page 9 lists parameters for the various WELL generators. You have to study the paper to understand the parameters, but the upper Δ<sub>1</sub> in the right-hand column is worth noticing.  Zero is the best value for Δ<sub>1</sub>--it's the number of dimensions in which the random numbers are *not* equidistributed.  So it's worth noticing, for example, that Δ<sub>1</sub> is not zero for WELL19937a or WELL19937b, but it *is* zero for WELL19937c.  Thus if you want a WELL generator and like the idea of a generator with period 2<sup>19937</sup> - 1, and you don't mind 624 words of state (624 * 32 = 19968), it's probably slightly better to use WELL19937c rather than the other two.  (This is probably one reason why WELL19937c is currently the default generator for Apache Commons Math lib, release 3.6.1, btw.)

Answer (score 2):

This is, I believe, log2(RNG period). Thus, WELL512a will have period of 2<sup>512</sup>, WELL1024 will have period 2<sup>1024</sup> etc

Reference: http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/wsc05rng.pdf, Table 1